# Excel transpose function returns a 0, multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I do have two worksheets.

In worksheet 1 I do have the following values horizontal listed:

```
A1 = 2010
B1 = 2011
C1 = 2012
```

In worksheet 2 I would like to list the values (2010, 2011, 2012) vertically. Like this:

```
A1 = 2010
A2 = 2011
A3 = 2012
```

I tried the following formula in worksheet 2:

`=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:C1)`

It returns to me only a `zero (0)`. But if I run this forumla in worksheet 1, it works.

As additional, the list of years in the worksheet 1 can be extend. So the transpose array has to be flexible.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In the older Excel, ones without Dynamic Array formula.  Put this in A1 and copy it down as many rows as would ever be needed:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,0,ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

The INDEX will return the year or a `0` if the cell is blank and by taking the reciprocal or the reciprocal we will get an error if `0` and then return `""`.

[image]

With the Dynamic Array formula we can just put:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!$1:$1,Sheet1!$1:$1<>""))
```

And it will spill the results

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. How can I define with `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!$1:$1,Sheet1!$1:$1<>""))` a range of data, that it should look up? 
For example, in worksheet 1 the data is listed in B2, C2, D2 until M2.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to realize? Thank you!